# Javascript php variable not passing with http_build_query

Tags: php, javascript

Why does this not work?

```
    var data1 = "<? http_build_query($_GET); ?>";
    var data2 = "buy.php?";
    var url = data2+data1
    document.getElementById('framebox').src = url;
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Does it crash? Pass the wrong variable? The right variable to the wrong place? Get the wrong data back?

Comment: What error do you get? And what does $_GET hold?

Comment: it does not add key1=value1&key2=value2&... after buy.php?

Comment: I'm confused. `$_GET` is a PHP array, you're trying to access it from javascript. Am I misunderstanding? If I'm not, you can't do what you want that way. Or is your javascript file running through the PHP parser on the way to the client? In which case there's probably a simpler way to do what you want.

Comment: so i can't load a php variable into a javascript variable?

Comment: No, PHP runs on the server and javascript runs on the client. They don't share any data.

Comment: @Gareth: I assume he's generating the Javascript code from PHP, if that's the case it'll work.

Comment: @Gareth: you can output PHP data in a JavaScript script.

Comment: @Alix Axel did however manage to share the data...

Comment: @MarcelKorpel: True, but I think in this case it's the other way around.

Comment: @AlixAxel I know you can, but generating javascript with PHP? That's a very complicated way of doing anything.

Comment: @Laurent Alix's solution sent the data from the server to the client. Like I said, if you're running the javascript file through the PHP parser on the way to the client there's probably a simpler solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `data1` is empty (PHP is not outputing anything), try:

```
var data1 = "<?= http_build_query($_GET); ?>"; // or
var data1 = "<?php echo http_build_query($_GET); ?>";
```

---

Any reason you're using PHP to build the query string instead of doing it directly in Javascript?

Comment: Pretty sure you can also use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

Comment: @NULL: Oh yeah, I wasn't even considering the PHP side of it. Still, if he had previously manipulable $_GET it's better to leave it as it is. Oh, and http_build_query() uses `&amp;` instead of `&` by default.

Comment: @AlixAxel Yes you are right about the changes in `$_GET` and most importantly you spotted the missing `echo` from php.

Comment: @Laurent: Check my update on using Javascript to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can also archive it the plain old pure javascript way:

```
var data1 = location.href.split('?').pop();
var data2 = "buy.php?";
var url = data2+data1
document.getElementById('framebox').src = url;
```

But it's much more fun to mix stuff.....

Comment: Ah, just what I was about to post! :P